# T-SQL: select * from table where column in (...) with duplicates without using union all

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, duplicates

I have a dataset in Excel where I have a few thousand id's. In a database I need a few columns to match these ids but some ids are listed twice in the Excel list (and they need to be there twice). I'm trying to write a query with an IN statement, but it automatically filters the duplicates. But I want the duplicates as well, otherwise I need to manually rearrange the data merge between the Excel and SQL results.

Is there any way to do something like

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE id IN (
 .. list of thousands ids
)
```

To also get the duplicates without using `UNION ALL` to prevent from firing thousands of seperate queries to the database?

Comment: Do you mean "list of thousands ids" has duplicates? Duplicates in the IN list doesn't matter. Or is it table that have duplicates? A plain SELECT removes nu duplicates.

Comment: The same id gets listed twice (for a few hundred ids) in the `IN`-list. SQL Server seems to think, well; I've done this before, no need to do it again. So, at some point duplicates are removed from the query result.

Comment: Hi Ben, is this still open? Do you need further help?

Comment: Hi @Shnugo, thanks for reminding me. I've fixed it using a small PHP script to create a large query unioning the results together. Based on the solutions I was faster off doing it this way. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a `left join` if you want to keep the duplicates.  If the ordering is important, then you should include that information as well.

Here is one method:

```
select t.*
from (values (1, id1), (2, id2), . . .
     ) ids(ordering, id) left join
     table t
     on t.id = ids.id
order by ids.ordering;
```

An alternative is to load the ids into a temporary table with an identity column to capture the ordering:

```
# Create the table
create table #ids (
    ordering int identity(1, 1) primary key,
    id
);

# Insert the ids    
insert into #ids (id)
    select @id;

# Use them in the query
select t.*
from #ids ids left join
     table t
     on t.id = ids.id
order by ids.ordering;
```

Comment: Unfortenately I don't have write permissions on the table (well, actually I'm glad since it's a production environment), so creating a table won't work. Also I'm on a SQL 2005 database (probably should have mentioned that), I'm having difficulties getting the values() syntax to work. Also this includes a lot of manual rewriting in the SQL query to split all ids into seperate value-groups. Thanks nonetheless.

Comment: @Ben . . . Instead of `values()` you can use `select . . . union all select . . . union all select`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That would indeed do what I was after. I've created a large query like that using a small PHP script and CSV-file with the ids I needed. Thanks, I'll accept your answer, + 1

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this correctly this is exactly the way `IN` is supposed to work...

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(value INT, content VARCHAR(100));
WITH RunningNummber AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS Nmbr
    FROM sys.objects
)
INSERT INTO @tbl
SELECT Nmbr,'Content for ' + CAST(Nmbr AS VARCHAR(100))
FROM RunningNummber;

--This ...
SELECT * FROM @tbl WHERE value IN(1,3,5);
-- ... is the same as this:
SELECT * FROM @tbl WHERE value IN(1,1,1,1,3,3,5,1,3,5);
```

If you want to combine two result-sets you have to join them...

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, I believe that is better that you import in a  table the values corresponding with the list of thousands ids and apply a Subquery to get the information that you will need.

Even once time that you got all the ids in the target table you can filter with a T-SQL for deleting duplicates values and avoid any future problem.